# Filter product by checkbox vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

i am trying to implement checkbox filter with vue js in laravel but its not working as expected. For first checkbox All , it works and show/hide all products when i check and uncheck checkbox. But for Tech,Entertainment and Fictional its not filtering product based on checkbox clicked.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="filter">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="0" /> All</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="1" /> Tech</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="2" /> Entertainment</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="3" /> Fictional</label>
                </div>

    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card" v-for="product in filteredProduct">
                    <div class="card-header">{{product. name}}</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img :src="product.image">
                        <p>{{product.price}}</p>
                        <p>{{product.category_id}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data:function(){
            return {
                products:[],
                selectedCategory: ["0"],

            }

        },
        computed: {
        filteredProduct: function() {
        var app = this;
        var category = app.selectedCategory;
        console.log(category)

        if(category.includes("0")) {
            return app.products;
        } else {

            return app.products.filter(function(p) {

            return category.includes(p.category_id);
        });

            }
        }
    },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Product mounted.')
            var app = this;
            axios.get('/products')
                .then(function (resp) {
                    app.products = resp.data;
                })
                .catch(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    alert("Could not load");
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

My guess is `category_id` in `products` array is of type **number**. But, `selectedCategory` array has numbers in string format. [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) uses *Strict equality* to check if the provided value exists in the array or not. This is why it works for `"0"` because it is provided as a string. If you change it to `p.category_id.toString()`, it will work:

Here's a working snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      products: [{ category_id: 1, name: "Tech 1" }, { category_id: 1,name: "Tech 2"},{ category_id: 2, name: "Entertainment 1" },{ category_id: 3, name: "Fictional 1" }],
      selectedCategory: ["0"],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredProduct: function() {
      const app = this,
        category = app.selectedCategory;

      if (category.includes("0"))
        return app.products;
      else
        return app.products.filter(p =>
          category.includes(p.category_id.toString())
        );
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="app">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="filter">
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="0" /> All</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="1" /> Tech</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="2" /> Entertainment</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="3" /> Fictional</label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card" v-for="product in filteredProduct">
      <div class="card-header">{{product. name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to remove All checkbox and want to show all products in page at first and want filter data based on only Tech,Fiction etc checkbox but not All checkbox. so if user do not check Tech check ,show  all results and filter data if he clicks Tech checkbox for example.How to do that?

Comment: @David if `Tech` is selected, you want to unselect `All`?

Comment: @David hi, please accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left of the answer